# Where do I apply the gradle idea plugin?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, gradle

The documentation says:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

This is easy but not very useful. It does not tell me **where** to apply the plug-in, for example. `allProjects`, perhaps? `subprojects`? Are there any places where it should ***not*** be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically all plugins are applied just after `buildscript` section at the very top of `build.gradle` script, especially in single module projects.

In multimodule projects you can apply the plugin in both `allprojects` and `subprojects`. It just depends if this plugin will be required in all the projects. If not and it's applied - nothing bad happens.